# Unable to Bind List of objects to Listview in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am trying to bind listview with list of user defined objects. I am getting the error as 
**ItemClass' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'**

Below is my Asp.net code :

```
 <asp:ListView ID ="listView" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>'>

        </asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>



    </asp:ListView>
```

I am trying to bind using the c# code :

```
 var list = new List<ItemClass>();

            ItemClass item1 = new ItemClass();
            item1.Name = "Aman";

            ItemClass item2 = new ItemClass();
            item2.Name = "Arjit";

            list.Add(item1);
            list.Add(item2);

            listView.DataSource = list;
            listView.DataBind();
```

Can you please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks

Amandeep

Comment: What is an `ItemClass` sounds like it doesn't have a property called `Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that `Name` is a `public` property in the class `ItemClass`, like this:

```
public class ItemClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Note: `Eval()` will only work on `public` properties.

Comment: It was an public property but was not having get and set. It is now working thanks a lot.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. If you feel this question helped you, then feel free to up-vote and/or accept the answer.